# How to read index based json in c# and convert it into object?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-mvc-5

It is the MVC 5 application consuming web service. Web service having the method to return the JSON data of string in following format.

```
 [WebMethod]
 [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
 public string GetCompanyData()
 {
        string jsonData = "[{\"1\":\"Message-Type\"},{\"28\":\"KEM\",\"3\":\"COMPANY1\",\"6\":\"218\",\"21\":\"6.8\",\"14\":\"33543\",\"16\":\"7188572.3\"},";
        jsonData +="{\"28\":\"KEM\",\"3\":\"COMPANY2\",\"6\":\"224.5\",\"21\":\"4.5\",\"14\":\"19058\",\"16\":\"4246936\"},";
        jsonData +="{\"28\":\"KEM\",\"3\":\"COMPANY3\",\"6\":\"79.9\",\"21\":\"3.4\",\"14\":\"81418\",\"16\":\"6320237.5\"},";
        jsonData +="{\"28\":\"KEM\",\"3\":\"COMPANY4\",\"6\":\"87\",\"21\":\"2.5\",\"14\":\"42277\",\"16\":\"3654459\"},";
        jsonData +="{\"28\":\"KEM\",\"3\":\"COMPANY5\",\"6\":\"103\",\"21\":\"2.3\",\"14\":\"1735\",\"16\":\"177450.4\"},";
        jsonData +="{\"28\":\"KEM\",\"3\":\"COMPANY6\",\"6\":\"108.1\",\"21\":\"2.1\",\"14\":\"269165\",\"16\":\"29039148.4\"},";
        jsonData +="{\"28\":\"KEM\",\"3\":\"COMPANY7\",\"6\":\"95.9\",\"21\":\"1.2\",\"14\":\"313\",\"16\":\"29479.7\"},";
        jsonData +="{\"28\":\"KEM\",\"3\":\"COMPANY8\",\"6\":\"51.1\",\"21\":\"1\",\"14\":\"117208\",\"16\":\"5954460.6\"},";
        jsonData +="{\"28\":\"KEM\",\"3\":\"COMPANY9\",\"6\":\"73.6\",\"21\":\"0.9\",\"14\":\"161593\",\"16\":\"11856197.6\"},";
        jsonData +="{\"28\":\"KEM\",\"3\":\"COMPANY10\",\"6\":\"40.1\",\"21\":\"0.55\",\"14\":\"220241\",\"16\":\"8782243.3\"}]";
        return jsonData;
  }
```

Trying to convert this into the object list.

```
 In controller :
  JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  var companyDataList = json_serializer.Deserialize<List<object>>(svc.GetCompanyData())
```

This is working fine. But there is iteration in JSON where, need to be perform the unboxing to custom object. Since keys are integer based unable to read data from JSON.
But generating JSON is having int as keys, so unable to read specific data.
How to read such JSON data.
Edited : Tried with Newtonsoft

```
object[] objectArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[]>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(companyDataList ));
```

But underlying list of data is resulting in immediate window like (for first ):

```
objIndex
{
  "28": "KEM",
  "3": "COMPANY1",
  "6": "218",
  "21": "6.8",
  "14": "33543",
  "16": "7188572.3"
}
    base: {
  "28": "KEM",
  "3": "COMPANY1",
  "6": "218",
  "21": "6.8",
  "14": "33543",
  "16": "7188572.3"
}
    Type: Object
```

**ANSWER:**

Added following class to extend :

```
 public static class Extensions
    {
        public static T ToObject<T>(this IDictionary<string, object> source, Dictionary<string, string> sourceDictionary)
          where T : class, new()
        {
            T someObject = new T();
            Type someObjectType = someObject.GetType();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in source)
            {
                if (sourceDictionary.Keys.Contains(item.Key) && (someObjectType.GetProperty(sourceDictionary[item.Key])!=null))
                    someObjectType.GetProperty(sourceDictionary[item.Key]).SetValue(someObject, item.Value, null);
            }
            return someObject;
        }

        public static IDictionary<string, object> AsDictionary(this object source, BindingFlags bindingAttr = BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        {
            return source.GetType().GetProperties(bindingAttr).ToDictionary
            (
                propInfo => propInfo.Name,
                propInfo => propInfo.GetValue(source, null)
            );

        }
    }
```

In Class method utilized this as :

```
var tempObjArray = json_serializer.Deserialize<object[]>(svc.GetTopByVolume());
        List<Symbol> topByVolumeList = new List<Symbol>();
        foreach (object tmpObject in tempObjArray)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> diTopByVolumes = (Dictionary<string, object>)tmpObject;
            Symbol someObject = diTopByVolumes.ToObject<Symbol>(StaticDictionary.TopByVolumeDictionary);
            topByVolumeList.Add(someObject);
        }
```

also in Global.asax in application start event specified added :

```
     public static Dictionary<string, string> TopByVolumeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 TopByVolumeDictionary.Add("3", "SYMBOLID");
            TopByVolumeDictionary.Add("6", "Property1");
            TopByVolumeDictionary.Add("14", "Property2");
            TopByVolumeDictionary.Add("16", "Property3");
            TopByVolumeDictionary.Add("21", "Property4");
```

Comment: Have you tried `JsonNet` from `NuGet`?

Comment: Yes, I tried with NewtonSoft Nuget. But it is giving same result.

Comment: So you want one really long string (as a json) that includes what looks like a List<Dictionary<string, string>>?

Comment: What I am trying to do is, I just want to prepare the list of custom object, that should hold list of company data. But since, property name cannot be int. So cannot read line data.28, data.3 :)

Comment: I can get that, I am just wondering if there is a C# object structure that would fit your needs and work well with something like JSON.NET. For example a Dictionary or hashtable would work well with your examples. Or even a class where you can `dictionaryList.Add("KEM","COMPANY1","218","6.8",33543","7188572.3")` and then deserialize the list as your JSON string...

Comment: Couldn't get, did you mean while iterating the list of object add current object(string) to dictionary of string and then serialize?

Comment: Negative mark accepted. Would ask voter for the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comments a little,

You might be better off building a simple class or object that reflects what your JSON is supposed to look like and then making a `List<companyObject>` the you can convert to a JSON string.

A quick example that might not reflect the structure you want would be something like:

A Class:

```
public class Company
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> companyObject = 
        new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public Dictionary<string, string> 
        Add(string twentyEight, string three, string six,
        string twentOne, string fourteen, string sixteen)
    {
        companyObject.Add("28", twentyEight);
        companyObject.Add("3", three);
        companyObject.Add("6", six);
        companyObject.Add("21", twentOne);
        companyObject.Add("14", fourteen);
        companyObject.Add("16", sixteen);
        return companyObject;
    }
}
```

And then a little code (not elegant)

```
List<Company> companyList = new List<Company>();
Company c = new Company();
c.Add("KEM", "COMPANY1", "218", "6.8", "33543", "7188572.3");
companyList.Add(c);

string newJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(companyList);
```

would create a JSON that looks like:

```
[{"companyObject":{"28":"KEM","3":"COMPANY1","6":"218","21":"6.8",
"14":"33543","16":"7188572.3"}}]
```

A list of two items would look like:

```
[{"companyObject":{"28":"KEM","3":"COMPANY1","6":"218","21":"6.8",
"14":"33543","16":"7188572.3"}},
{"companyObject":{"28":"KEM","3":"COMPANY2","6":"219","21":"7.2",
"14":"35200","16":"7188111.7"}}]
```

I'd tweak the class depending on what you really want, but as a quick rough concept I think it is a better approach.

Comment: Perhaps good answer. But need to play with string to get the string values "KEM", "COMPANY1", "218", "6.8", "33543", "7188572.3", which is suppose to be not standard way. The code would be specific rather generic. Having lots of web methods to perform same in the application. Hence scenario wise it may be good approach but not feasible for other methods.

Comment: A Dictionary is a Key Pair set, so the method can absolutely pass dynamic data for either the key, the value, both or neither. you can also manipulate members directly with `c["28"] = "KEM"` or ` if (c["14"] == "" | c["14"] == null) {///stuff to fix }`

Comment: Thanks, Helpful. I could achieve by referencing your answer. Edited my answer in question itself. May helpful to others